# Find an expression in terms of $z$ only.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find an expression of the following equations in terms of $z$.
Where $z = x + iy$, I am not allowed to use conjugate z.

$\text{Sin}(x)\text{Sinh}(y)$ + $i\text{Cos}(x)\text{Cosh}(y)$

Knowing that:

$\text{Sin}(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$

$\text{Cos}(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2i}$

$\text{Sinh}(y) = \frac{e^{y} - e^{-y}}{2}$

$\text{Cosh}(y) = \frac{e^{y} + e^{-y}}{2}$

I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: $z = x+iy$? Btw, please use Latex/Mathjax.

Comment: Yes, z=x+iy. I am not able to use Latex at the moment. My laptop is broken.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the complex conjugate of $z$? You can write in Latex code in the editor, no need for your Laptop :)

Comment: No, not allowed to use conjugate z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\cos(x+yi)&=\cos(x)\cos(yi)-\sin(x)\sin(yi)\\&=\cos(x)\cosh(yi)-\sin(x)\sinh(y)i\\&=-i\bigl(\sin(x)\sinh(y)+\cos(x)\cosh(y)i\bigr)\end{align}and therefore$$\sin(x)\sinh(y)+\cos(x)\cosh(y)i=i\cos(x+yi).$$So, your expression is equal to $i\cos(z)$.

Comment: Ok I see. Only it is not possible that the final expression contains conjugate z.

Comment: seems like you mixed up some trigonometric identities, see songs answer!

Comment: @Stockfish I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible starting point: we have
$$4i \sin(x) \sinh(y) = (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})(e^y-e^{-y}) = e^{ix+y}-e^{ix-y}-e^{-ix+y}+-e^{-ix-y}.$$
Now use $iz = -y+ix$.

Comment: Ok thankyou. I shall try it.